# Resin Server - Can't install into Eclipse kepler

Tags: eclipse, centos

I'm using CentOS 6.4. I have downloaded Resin server from the [this official website](http://www.caucho.com/download/). I have the folder in /home/admin/.  I followed [this site](http://wiki3.caucho.com/Eclipse#Installing_from_the_Resin_Eclipse_plugin_update_site_.28Helios_and_above.29) for adding resin server into Eclipse. but couldn't able to see resin option. Is there any way to add resin server into Eclipse. ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you obtain a license from Caucho? From the official website:

```
Evaluation License
Evaluation license is free of charge, contact us for a 60-day key.
```